# Add several functions as hooks in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

How could I simplify something like the following code in my `init.el` file?

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-revert-mode)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-org-cdlatex)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'smartparens-mode)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'abbrev-mode)
```

I have several other rows like this, including some lambda functions added to `org-mode-hook`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I would strongly advice against adding `lambda` functions to hooks. The main reason is that if you change the content and reevaluate the `add-hook` expression, the hook contains *both* the old and new lambda expression. The second reason is that it looks bad when you inspect a hook -- it's better to see a function name compared to a large lambda expression.

Instead, I would suggest using:

```
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (turn-on-auto-revert-mode)
  (turn-on-org-cdlatex)
  (smartparens-mode 1)
  (abbrev-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
```

A side note: You can use `global-auto-revert-mode` to enable auto-revert on all buffers, that way you don't have to enable it for all major modes.

Answer (score 3):

I use a simple `dolist`:

```
(dolist (fn '(turn-on-auto-revert-mode
              turn-on-org-cdlatex
              smartparens-mode
              abbrev-mode))
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook fn))
```

This let's you still remove individual hooks afterwards, with `remove-hook` or from the customize interface.